# Is a manual QUdpSocket implementation right for image streaming? or are there better ways?

Tags: c++, qt, udp, streaming, qudpsocket

I'm creating a remote viewer for an image processing application and need to send the results over the network so they can be recorded. I'm currently trying to stream the images with a UDP socket based on QUpdSocket. UDP is fine because I don't need every image so I can deal with potential packet loss. When testing the implementation below on localhost I can get >20 fps which is way more than I'll need in the real application. But as soon as I move to 2 PCs on the network I hardly receive any images. I know packets are getting through because I can see the network activity but I'm ether dropping loads or there's something else weird going on with the decoding/rendering.

The implementation is pretty basic so any pointers would be appreciated. Or should I not be doing this myself because there are good libraries for this sort of thing?

Sender:
Sits in a look waiting for the receiver to send a packet and identify itself, after one is found, snaps an image splits it into the datagram size (here 508) then send x number of datagrams.

```
while (!foundReceiver) {
                while (!socket.waitForReadyRead(500));
                QByteArray buffer;
                buffer.resize(socket.pendingDatagramSize());

                socket.readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, nullptr);
                if (strcmp("RECEIVER", buffer) == 0) {
                    foundReceiver = true;
                    printf_s("Found receiver on : %s", sender.toString().toStdString().c_str());
                }
            }

            printf_s("ctrl-c to quit\n");

            while (!socket.hasPendingDatagrams()) {
                cv::Mat img = ih->getLatestImage();
                if (!img.empty()) {
                    std::vector<uint8_t> buf;
                    std::vector<int> params;
                    params.push_back(IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
                    params.push_back(80);
                    cv::imencode(".jpg", img, buf, params);

                    char imgDetails[28];
                    int numPackets = std::ceil((float)buf.size() / (float)datagramSize);
                    sprintf_s(imgDetails, "START %04d %04d %04d %06d", img.rows, img.cols, numPackets, datagramSize);

                    bool result = socket.writeDatagram(imgDetails, sizeof(imgDetails), sender, 9000);

                    for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {
                        int start = i * datagramSize;
                        int end = ((i + 1) * datagramSize);
                        if (end > buf.size())
                            end = buf.size();
                        std::vector<uint8_t> shortBuff((end - start) + 4);
                        char np[5];
                        sprintf_s(np, "%04d", i);
                        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                            shortBuff[j] = np[j];
                        std::copy(buf.begin() + start, buf.begin() + end, shortBuff.begin() + 4);
                        bool result = socket.writeDatagram((char*)shortBuff.data(), shortBuff.size(), sender, 9000);
                    }
                }
                camera.ExecuteSoftwareTrigger();
            }
            QByteArray buffer;
            buffer.resize(socket.pendingDatagramSize());

            socket.readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, nullptr);
            if (strcmp("RECEIVER DISCONNECT", buffer) == 0) {
                foundReceiver = false;
                printf_s("Receiver %s disconnected", sender.toString().toStdString().c_str());
            }
        }
```

Receiver:
QUdpSocket calls datagramPending which reads the datagram, sends it to precessDatagram which decides whether is a header or an image packet. If its an image packet moves the contents into a buffer at the location specified by the 4 digit number at the start of the packet. When all image packets have been received convert the buffer into an image.

```
void UDPSocket::datagramPending() {
    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray buffer;
        buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());

        QHostAddress sender;

        socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, nullptr);

        emit receivedDatagram(buffer, sender);
    }
}

void Receiver::processDatagram(QByteArray buff, QHostAddress address) {

if (buff.size() > 0) {
    ImageHeader ih = isStartPacket(buff);

    if (ih.startPacket) {
        streamStarted = true;
        senderAddress = address;

        currentImageRows = ih.rows;
        currentImageCols = ih.cols;
        currentImageNumPackets = ih.numPackets;
        currentImagePacketSize = ih.packetSize;

        rawBuffer = std::vector<uint8_t>(currentImagePacketSize * currentImageNumPackets);

        numReceivedPackets = 0;
    }
    else {
        if (rawBuffer.size() > 0) {
            std::vector<uint8_t> packetNumChar(5);
            std::move(buff.begin(), buff.begin() + 4, packetNumChar.begin());

            int packetNumber;
            packetNumChar[4] = '\0';
            sscanf_s((const char*)packetNumChar.data(), "%04d", &packetNumber);

            int start = packetNumber * currentImagePacketSize;

            if ((start + buff.size()) < rawBuffer.size())
                std::move(buff.begin() + 4, buff.end(), rawBuffer.begin() + start);

            numReceivedPackets++;
            if (numReceivedPackets == currentImageNumPackets)
                emit receivedImage(rawBuffer);
        }
    }
}
}

ImageHeader Receiver::isStartPacket(QByteArray buff) {
    int rows = 0, cols = 0, numPackets = 0, packetSize = 0;
    bool startPacket = false;

    if (strncmp(buff.data(), startHeader, 5) == 0)
        startPacket = true;

    if (startPacket) 
        sscanf_s(buff.data(), "START %04d %04d %04d %06d", &rows, &cols, &numPackets, &packetSize);

    ImageHeader ih = { startPacket, rows, cols, numPackets, packetSize };

    return ih;
}

void Receiver::receivedImage(std::vector<uint8_t> buff) {
    rawImageData = cv::Mat(1, buff.size(), CV_8UC1, buff.data());
    currentImage = cv::imdecode(rawImageData, IMREAD_COLOR);
}
```

Comment: Always when using UDP you should be wary of sending too much data. I would try to throttle your data and see if that improves situation. The reason is that once you send too much data over UDP some parts of network stack such as hardware may drop packages deliberately or even block completely.

Comment: Thanks, Lennart. Any idea by how much?

Comment: Depends on available bandwidh. Basically you risk flooding the buffers and that creates congestion. I learned about this on the following great article (I liked to way back machine since the site seems to be down):  https://web.archive.org/web/20181107181433/https://gafferongames.com/post/reliability_ordering_and_congestion_avoidance_over_udp/  It is a part of a series of articles on networking which is highly recommended. Whole series is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20181107181458/https://gafferongames.com/tags/networking

Comment: Thanks, that's a good read. Introducing a delay in between packets seems to have helped too.